# SQL loops and query

Tags: sql

I need to apply an ST_distance query to find distance from the given table. How should I tell my query to take points one after the other consecutively on its own or like if the teacher specifies to find the distance between point 3 and 5? I just know this.

It'll be great if the queries are simple cause I'm newbie at this. I'm used to Python but not SQL.

```
SELECT name,ST_AsText(geom)
FROM   testpoints
LIMIT  2;

select ST_Distance(
ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(73.08435381390693 33.72475853055647)'),
ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(73.09256019460882 33.73467209912755)')
);
```

[image]

Comment: What did your teacher say when you asked him?

Comment: This is more of a SQL fundamentals question than a GIS one, probably better researched over in [dba.se]. Your search term is "self join"

Comment: @Berend my teacher has just asked to put simple spatial queries like finding distance between two points, and area of a polygon , buffer and so on.. Now, I was thinking to upgrade to like if I'm given this kind of .shp file  , then how to calculate areas of specified points or how to apply a loop that it calculates all the given geometry points.